# Copy attributes from case class

Tags: scala

```
case class A(a:Int ,b:Int,c:Int,d:Int)

case class B(a:Int ,b:Int,c:Int,d:Int,e:List[Int],f:List[Int])

val a = A(1,2,3,4)

val b = B(a.a,a.b,a.c,a.d,List(1,2),List(2,3))
```

Currently, I am manually copying class A object to B like `a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d`

Is there any alternate way to do something like

```
val b = B(a.attributes.toList,List(1,2),List(2,3))
```

Comment: You may want to implement an apply method in B‘s companion object doing the copying. Such that B can be instantiated with B(a, list1, list2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access and control of the `B` code then you can add as many different constructors as you like.

```
case class A(a:Int, b:Int, c:Int, d:Int)

case class B(a:Int ,b:Int,c:Int,d:Int,e:List[Int],f:List[Int])

object B {
  def apply(a:A, e:List[Int], f:List[Int]) = new B(a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d, e, f)
}

val a = A(1,2,3,4)

val b1 = B(a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d, List(1,2), List(2,3))
val b2 = B(a, List(4,5), List(9,1))
```

If you can't, or would rather not, modify `A` or `B` then you might add one or more implicit conversion methods.

```
implicit class A2B(a:A) {
  def toB(e:List[Int], f:List[Int]) :B = B(a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d, e, f)
}
val a = A(1,2,3,4)

val b1 = B(a.a, a.b, a.c, a.d, List(1,2), List(2,3))
val b3 = a.toB(List(32,12), List(544,2))
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some Scala libraries that focus on typesafe, boilerplate-free copying between case classes. I like Chimney:

https://scalalandio.github.io/chimney/

You can do as follows:

```
  case class A(a:Int,b:Int,c:Int,d:Int)
  case class B(a:Int,b:Int,c:Int,d:Int,e:List[Int],f:List[Int])

  val a = A(1,2,3,4)

  // if additional parameters e and f in B would have default values
  val b1 = a.transformInto[B]

  // explicitly set additional parameters in B to constant values
  val b2 = a.into[B]
            .withFieldConst(_.e, List(1,2))
            .withFieldConst(_.f, List(1,2))
            .transform
```

Answer (score 1):

try this
      `

```
 case class A(a:Int, b:Int, c:Int, d:Int)

 case class B(a:List[Any], e:List[Int], f:List[Int])


 val a = A(1,2,3,4)

 val b = B(a.productIterator.toList,List(1,2),List(2,3))
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
case class A(a:Int, b:Int, c:Int, d:Int)

case class B(a:A, e:List[Int], f:List[Int])

val a = A(1,2,3,4)

val b = B(a,List(1,2),List(2,3))
```

Comment: This I am aware of, but for example, both classes could be different